# Python: Get the right color for different plots in a single figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm struggling to get different colored lines for different plots in my graph and I can't find the solution online.

Below is the current figure which points out the problem with the lines. Namely, each line should be a single color, but they are switching in the middle.

[image]

```py
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Constants
length = 1.0  # Length of the tube in meters
diameter = 10 / 1000  # Diameter of the tube in meters
emissivity = 0.73  # Emissivity of the tube
outside_temp_list = [-40, -20, 0, 20, 40, 60, 70]  # Outside temperatures in °C
outside_pressure = 1 * 10**5  # Outside pressure in Pascal
initial_pressure = 10 * 10**5  # Initial pressure of hydrogen inside the tube in Pascal
initial_temp = 25 + 273  # Initial temperature of hydrogen inside the tube in Kelvin
Cv = 22  # Specific heat capacity of hydrogen at 10 bars and 25 °C in J/(mol·K)
k = 0.10  # Thermal conductivity of hydrogen at 10 bars and 25 °C in W/(m·K)

# Calculate area and volume of the tube
radius = diameter / 2
area = 2 * math.pi * radius * length
volume = math.pi * radius * radius * length

# Calculate number of moles of hydrogen inside the tube
R = 8.314  # Universal gas constant in J/(mol·K)
n = initial_pressure * volume / (R * initial_temp)

# Create lists to store the results
time_list = []
temperature_list = []
pressure_list = []

# Perform the calculations for each outside temperature scenario
for outside_temp in outside_temp_list:
    time = 0
    temperature = initial_temp
    pressure = initial_pressure
    
    # Update k and Cv for specific temperatures
    if outside_temp == 40:
        k = 0.12
        Cv = 25
    elif outside_temp == 60:
        k = 0.2
        Cv = 26
    elif outside_temp == 70:
        k = 0.3
        Cv = 27
    
    while abs(temperature - (outside_temp + 273)) > 0.001:
        time_list.append(time)
        temperature_list.append(temperature)
        pressure_list.append(pressure)
    
        dt = 1
    
        # Calculate the rate of heat transfer by radiation
        sigma = 5.67e-8
        Q_rad = -emissivity * sigma * area * (temperature**4 - (outside_temp + 273)**4) * dt
    
        # Calculate the rate of heat transfer by conduction
        Q_cond = -k * area * (temperature - (outside_temp + 273)) * dt / length
    
        # Update the temperature and pressure
        temperature += (Q_rad + Q_cond) / (n * Cv)
        pressure = (n * R * temperature) / volume
    
        time += dt

# Generate the table
table = zip(time_list, temperature_list, pressure_list)
print("Time (sec)\tTemperature (K)\tPressure (Pa)")
for row in table:
    print(f"{row[0]}\t\t{row[1]:.2f}\t\t{row[2]:.2f}")

# Convert pressure from Pascal to bar
pressure_list_bar = [p / 100000 for p in pressure_list]

# Plot the results
plt.plot(pressure_list_bar[:len(time_list)//7], time_list[:len(time_list)//7], label="-40 °C", color='blue')
plt.plot(pressure_list_bar[len(time_list)//7:2*len(time_list)//7], time_list[len(time_list)//7:2*len(time_list)//7], label="-20 °C", color='red')
plt.plot(pressure_list_bar[2*len(time_list)//7:3*len(time_list)//7], time_list[2*len(time_list)//7:3*len(time_list)//7], label="0 °C", color='green')
plt.plot(pressure_list_bar[3*len(time_list)//7:4*len(time_list)//7], time_list[3*len(time_list)//7:4*len(time_list)//7], label="+20 °C", color='purple')
plt.plot(pressure_list_bar[4*len(time_list)//7:5*len(time_list)//7], time_list[4*len(time_list)//7:5*len(time_list)//7], label="+40 °C", color='orange')
plt.plot(pressure_list_bar[5*len(time_list)//7:6*len(time_list)//7], time_list[5*len(time_list)//7:6*len(time_list)//7], label="+60 °C", color='yellow')
plt.plot(pressure_list_bar[6*len(time_list)//7:], time_list[6*len(time_list)//7:], label="+70 °C", color='brown')

plt.title("Pressure vs Time")
plt.xlabel("Pressure (bar)")
plt.ylabel("Time (sec)")
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: The linked image has different colored lines. What is wrong about it?

Comment: Hello Jared,

Sorry, I realized that I wasn't precise enough. 

For example: the curve on the left should be blue only and not blue and red.
Here you can find what I meant :
https://ibb.co/jvkprKj

Comment: It sounds like you're just slicing the data wrong. I don't know which part of the data corresponds to which temperature line to be able to help with that.

Comment: Yes, I guess you're right. When the program finishes the first loop (with the temperature of -40 °C), goes to the next one ( T = -20 °C), and plots the lines, something is wrong. However, when I looked at the results in the table, the values were correct to what I expected. So I don't know where the mistake is happening during the plotting part.  
 <hr/> 
The first data, time 0 to 72 sec, correspond to the data at -40 °C. After, when the time is reset to 0, the data from 0 to 56 sec correspond to the data at -20 °C, etc. Maybe the mistake is here?

Comment: I have posted a solution that explains how to do this properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you assumed all the lines have the same number of points when they do not. Since we know that each line starts at time 0, we can loop through the time list and save the points where the time is 0. Now, we know that for a given index, that is the start of a timespan and the next index is the start of the next. So, we can slice the data using every two indices. An easy way to loop through that is to `zip` the list from the beginning to the second to last element with the same list starting at the second element. We will also need to account for the last timespan, so we can append -1 to the list, since -1 indexes the last element.

I also made two other changes.

1. I put the labels and colors in lists.
2. I swapped the axes to have time (the independent variable) on the x-axis and pressure (the dependent variable) on the y-axis since that is the convention.

```py
time_resets = [i for i, time in enumerate(time_list) if time == 0]
time_resets.append(-1)
temperatures = ["-40 °C", "-20 °C", "0 °C", "+20 °C", "+40 °C", "+60 °C", "+70 °C"]
colors = ["blue", "red", "green", "purple", "orange", "yellow", "brown"]

for start, stop, temperature, color in zip(time_resets[:-1],
                                           time_resets[1:],
                                           temperatures,
                                           colors):
    plt.plot(time_list[start:stop], pressure_list_bar[start:stop],
             label=temperature, color=color)

plt.xlabel("Time (sec)")
plt.ylabel("Pressure (bar)")
plt.title("Pressure vs Time")
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Jared, I understand my mistake! >You help me a lot for this case!